# How can I use Emacs in a SSH sever that I logged in through emacs terminal?

Tags: ssh, editing, remote, server

I really like the emacs terminal but each time I use it to log into my server. I don't know how to use emacs to edit files on the server.

Or it is not possible to do it? I can only edit files on server via ssh edit? However, in the latter case, how can I edit file as root user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Tramp. You can edit a file on another machine using the syntax `/ssh:user@machine:/path/to/file`. If you take `sudo` instead of `ssh`, and empty `user` and `machine`, you can edit a local file as root. Like `/sudo::/path/to/file`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is how can I use sudo when I want to edit files on the server.

Comment: @LifeWorks [multi hop](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html)?

Comment: Yes, mutihop. `/ssh:user@machine|sudo:machine:/path/to/file` let you edit files with `root` credentials on the other machine, after first login as `user`.

Comment: There are several more examples of editing local and remote files as sudo in the tramp help screens in emacs (C-h i and look under Tramp, Multi-hops). Enter them directly as Michael Albinus shows in his response or setup defaults using the link that npostavs provided.

Comment: I tried with @Mi